# How to acces folder in GitHub repository to read all files?

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

Trying to access a folder on my GitHub repository with JS. Works locally but not on Github Pages.

I'm trying to access a folder in my repository to get all files that are included.
The code works perfectly on my computer but not on GitHub Pages.

This is the folder I'm trying to access: https://if4x.github.io/images/photography/page/

This is the JS code that I'm using

```
var folder = "../images/photography/page";
        var folder = "../images/photography/page";

    $.ajax({
        url: folder,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
                    // Construct the image URL
                    var imageUrl = val;

                    // Make an AJAX request to load the content of the corresponding .txt file
                    $.ajax({
                        url: val.replace(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/, ".txt"),
                        success: function (txtData) {
                            var Text = txtData.trim().split("\n"); // Trim to remove leading and trailing spaces

                            // Append the image with alt text
                            $(".gallery.content").append("<div class='gallery entry'><div class='image-container'><img src=" + val + " alt=" + Text[0] + "></div><div class='text-container'><h2>" + Text[1] + "</h2><p>" + Text.splice(2) + " </p></div></div>");
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            console.error("Error loading .txt file:", err);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: GIthub Pages does not have an "automatic" directory listing - if this is what you are looking for.  There is no concept of "accessing a folder" , when the server does not implement it. Anyway: you have to be more specific what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to access the folder and get all the files so I can add them to my html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative paths will not work on Github Pages for your use case since the Github pages is deployed on a URL different from your repository URL. Change the `folder` value to `https://if4x.github.io/images/photography/page/`.